# Fuzzy String Match in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

My question is whether we can use kind of partially match function within our sparql queries. I know lots of functions are now available here https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strings, and an effective use of regex does the job. I was still wondering whether any predefined functions, best-practioces etc are already available for strings' fuzzy match. For instance,
"I'm a student" matches with "I'm a Student" or "I am aa Student" or "I am a Students"
"That's great!" matches with "This is great." or "That's great." or "Great!"
These are just a few examples in which semantices are taken into account and typos, grammatical mistakes or different wordings are ignored.

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

I've tried to use regex.

Comment: there is no such feature in standard SPARQL. Depending on the triple store, you can check for fulltext index support, e.g. by means of Lucene

Comment: To that end, which triple store / RDF datastore are you using?

Comment: I'm using three different triple stores, Marklogic, Jena, and  Stardog. Among them, Stardog offers kind of full-text and embedding. I was wondering if there is a solution that i can use across the three triple stores.

Comment: no, there is no portable solution - there is in fact no fulltext search feature in SPARQL 1.1, not is there anything beyond like fuzzy matching. That's one of the limitations of SPARQL 1.1, almost each triple store vendor added their own solution, usually by added a custom "magic" predicate (e.g. Jena, GraphDB, Stardog, Virtuoso) or via `SERVICE` clause (e.g. Blazegraph). And even than, fuzzy match which is indeed more expensive might not be supported. I know that Jena does use Lucene as backend, so you might be able to setup their fuzzy matching

Comment: Indeed, for thinks like "semantic similarity" you'll have to make use of something beyond lexical matching, like the embedding based support you mentioned in Stardog or GraphDB. At least that's necessary for your example with *"This is great." or "That's great." or "Great!"" which needs some mechanism that captures the meaning and sentiment.

Comment: I'm also not sure if any text search or semantic search will make it to SPARQL 1.2, tickets are open: https://github.com/w3c/sparql-dev/issues/40

Comment: Thank you very much @UninformedUser for your informative comments.